# Shortcut to capture a custom ROI with shutter in Xubuntu

Tags: screenshot, shutter

From Greenshot, I'm used to capture custom ROIs (region of interest) ony my screen.

However, there seems no shortcut to do that. In this [small tutorial](http://blog.zot24.com/keyboard-shortcuts-on-shutter-0-90-1-with-ubuntu-13-10/), the author referes to Unity to setup the hotkey ´Shift Ctrl Print´ to do this (though, Ubuntu 13), but I have Xubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In 18.04, `man shutter` has:

```
CAPTURE MODE OPTIONS
    -s, --select=[X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT]
            Capture an area of the screen. Providing X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT is optional.
```

In Xubuntu 18.04, to set <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> as a shortcut to use `Shutter` to capture an area of interest, open the Whisker Menu, the icon for which is usually located at the left of your panel, click on `Settings` in the right column, and then on `Keyboard` in the left column. A window titled `Keyboard` opens. In there, click on the `Application Shortcuts` tab near the top and then on the `Add` button near the lower left (marked in red).

As soon as you click `Add`, a smaller window, titled `Shortcut Command`, pops up in which you need to type or paste in the command for which you want to assign a keyboard shortcut. In this case, we'll use `shutter -s`.

[image: Shutter 1]

Once you're done entering the command, press the `Okay` button near the lower right corner.

Now, another window, `Command Shortcut`, appears.

[image: Shutter 02]

In this one, you need to simultaneously press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and that will be reflected in the window.

[image: Shutter 03]

Once you release the keys you pressed, that window disappears, the shortcut is established, and you can see it listed. It is functional immediately.

[image: Shutter 04]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom shortcut by adding a key binding in ubuntu. open up system settings and hit keyboard. shortcuts tab, then hit custom shortcuts. Hit add shortcut, name it, give it the command "shutter –s". hit apply. highlight your new shortcut and double tap in unassigned on the bindings window. press the key you want to be the shortcut.

restart shutter.
reboot may be required.